# PHP $_GET variable usage

Tags: php

When using the $_GET functionality, I'm getting errors sometimes and warning other times and I wanted to know why.

The below snip-it works:

```
Fries: $_GET[chkFries]<br>
```

But, when I put a single quote around chkFries, I get an error, why?

The below snip-it works:

```
if(!empty($_GET["chkFries"]))
```

But, when I remove the double quotes, I get the following error, why?

> Notice: Use of undefined constant chkFries - assumed 'chkFries' in /var/www/html/checkBoxDemo/checkBoxDemo.php on line 20

Below are two files in my program.

```
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Fast food ordering</TITLE>
</HEAD>

<BODY>
<H1>Menu</H1>

<FORM action = "checkBoxDemo.php">
<UL>
    <LI><input type="checkbox" name="chkFries" value="1.00">Fries
    <LI><input type="checkbox" name="chkSoda" value="0.50">Soda
    <LI><input type="checkbox" name="chkBurger" value="2.00">Burger
    <LI><input type="checkbox" name="chkShake" value="0.25">Shake
</UL>

<input type="submit">
</FORM>

</BODY>
</HTML>
```

**PHP Program**
    
    
    Check Box Demo PHP

```
<BODY>
<H1>This is what you ordered</H1>

<?PHP
print <<<HERE

Fries: $_GET[chkFries]<br>
Soda: $_GET[chkSoda]<br>
Burger: $_GET[chkBurger]<br>
Shake: $_GET[chkShake]<br>
HERE;

$total=0;

if(!empty($_GET["chkFries"]))
$total=$total+$_GET['chkFries'];

if (!empty($_GET['chkSoda']))
$total=$total+$_GET['chkSoda'];

if (!empty($_GET['chkBurger']))
$total=$total+$_GET['chkBurger'];

if (!empty($_GET['chkShake']))
$total=$total+$_GET['chkShake'];

print "Your total is: $total";
?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: Yes, it will give that warning, unless you define a constant called `chkFries`

Comment: Read up on strings http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php and find "heredoc" in there. You're thinking that just because the unquoted GET arrays in heredoc work, that you could do the same thing for your conditional statement. This being the *real* answer for this question. Had you done `Fries: $_GET['chkFries']<br>` you'd of gotten an error about it also.

Comment: Well..Just as @MarkBaker said that only constants can be passed as arguments without any quotes & since you don't have any constants with those names so that's why you are getting error instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues:

1. Your `<li>` tags needs closing
2. Using quotes inside a quoted block can be problematic

I suggest you simplify things a bit:

```
print "Fries: " . $_GET["chkFries"] . "<br/>" .
    "Soda: " . $_GET["chkSoda"] . "<br/>" .
    "Burger: " . $_GET["chkBurger"] . "<br/>" .
    "Shake: " . $_GET["chkShake"] . "<br/>";
```

Comment: That isn't what the question is about.

Answer (score 0):

## FYI

First of all: NEVER use unescaped `$_GET`, `$_POST`, `$_REQUEST`, `$_SESSION`. Further reading: http://phpsecurity.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Cross-Site-Scripting-%28XSS%29.html

Secondly, you should post the notice. It looks like you are using undfined variables. As long as you have no value for your checkbox, the variable will not exist. For example when you are browsing to this site for the first time.

## Solution

```
<?php 

  $order = array();

  $order['fries'] = htmlentities($_GET["chkFries"]);
  // Copy and past for the rest

?> 


<BODY>
<H1>This is what you ordered</H1>


  <!-- Copy and past for the rest -->
  <? if($fries) ?>
    Fries: <? echo $fries; ?>
  <? endif ?>

  <?

    $total = 0;

    foreach ($order as $price) {
      if($price > 0) $total += $price;
    }

    echo "Your total is: $total";

  ?>
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

*This code is untested.*

## Reason for the notice

You have been using constans in your arrays because of the missing quotation marks in your HERE section.